# Android: prevent display from turning off

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've written a small game, that is only controlled via some sensors. There is no touchscreninput or something similar.

The problem is, that after a few seconds of gaming, the screen turns off (because of no touch-input)

Is there something like a manifest-entry that prevents the screen from this behaviour?

regards

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest would be adding `android:keepScreenOn="true"` to the layout in your xml.

Comment: for my small app, this was exactly what i've searched:) thanks it works

Answer (score 15):

use this code in the your game's Activity as first line in the onCreate() after the super call:

```
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

This will result in the System handling the screen for you.

Best wishes,
Tim

Answer (score 2):

use WakeLock

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "My Tag");
mWakeLock.acquire();
```

and put the permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

dont forget to release that lock in your `onStop()`

Answer (score 1):

You can request a WakeLock as specified here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html